# Entity Framework seeding complex objects?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to figure out how to seed a complex entity framework code first object. Currently the code I have allows me to insert simple objects but there has to be a way do more complex items, i.e. Address with an AdressType field.

```
context.AddressTypes.AddOrUpdate(
         p => p.Name,
         new AddressType { Name = "Original" },
         new AddressType { Name = "Shipping" },
         new AddressType { Name = "Billing" }
        );
context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(
         a => a.Address1,
         new Address
          {
          Address1 = "1234 West Main",
          City = "Hannibal",
          Region = "MO",
          PostalCode = "12345",
          Country = "USA",
          Type = context.AddressTypes.Where(a=>a.Name=="Original")
          });
```

But while I can "Find" an addresstype by id I can't do a "Where" name equals. Find would work except that I can not guarantee what the id will be with each seed and want to base it on name instead.

Any suggestions on how to do this?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Added a reference System.Linq to the seed class. Then was able to the where clause.